# How can i dispose a sound in java?

Tags: java, audio

Ok so i have this class to play sounds for my game :

```
package sound;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
public class GameSounds 
{
    private static int count = 0;
    public static void play(String path)
    {
        try
        {
            URL audioInStream = GameSounds.class.getResource(path);
            AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioInStream);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(inputStream);
            clip.start();
            if(count > 60)
            {
                clip.stop();
                count = 0;
            }
            count++;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have like 10 levels.. and in the 8th or 9th level it gives an error "out of memory" and it tells me that the error comes from this class which i believe it's not getting rid of the sounds after using them... So my question is how can i do it? i tried something with try catch and final and clip.dispose() but apperently it didn't work out..

Comment: and also i tried that thing with the count and clip.stop() it seems that it didn't work out as well..

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calling `close()` on your `AudioInputStream`.

Comment: thanks the code gives no error but i didn't test it out yet so i'm going to test it out right now and come back with an answer